# How do I test customized stream playback paths in Red5

Tags: red5

I have a Red5 application that I inherited from a previouse developer and I am trying to get it running correctly. I am able to start the Red5 server and stream video files from my /webapps/myapp/streams/ directory. I am able to test this by going to http://localhost:8080/myApps/streams/testVid.mp4 and the video plays normally.

However, I need to be able to stream my videos from any directory in my file explorer. The application already has a Application.java, a CustomFilenameGenerator.java, the needed bean for CustomFilenameGenerator in red5-web.xml and a playbackPath and recordPath in my red5-web.properties file.

From my research it seems like the previous developer that worked on this project was probably able to get the streaming working from a custom path, but I am not sure how to get it running.

**Assuming that everything with the application/configurations is correct how do I actually test it, if the files I want to stream are in C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\StreamRecordings?**

I have tried going to http://localhost:8080/myApp/StreamRecordings/testVid.mp4 but I get 404 error (probably since StreamRecordings is not in a myApp subdirectory.

Thanks!

Comment: The original developer split the paths for possible transcoding / processing steps, if I understand correctly. The play and record path should be the same directory in all other cases, there is no other means for playing from the recording path. I know that sounds confusing, but once you have it, it makes more sense. Also make sure your return for absolute is true, if you dont use a relative path.